# How to create int values with '0' prefix

Tags: objective-c

I am using Objective-C and trying to create int values that are between 1-99 and if less than 10 I would like them to show as 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, etc. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to work with strings in order to do that. concatenate the string "0" with the string representation of your integer if your int is below 10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides PengOne's answer, you could also use a format string.

```
NSLog(@"%02d", 3);
```

says 'print the following int with at least 2 digits' and will add the leading 0 if it only has one. It will print

```
03
```

Or if you want an NSString,

```
NSString *tst = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", 5];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply print `i` with a `0` when it's less than `10` using

```
NSLog(@"%@%d", (i<10 ? @"0" : @""), i );
```

Alternately, if you want a string,

```
NSString *paddedNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",(i<10 ? @"0" : @""),i];
```